# iOS send sms in background or call phone without dialog clicking

Tags: ios, offline

I was asked to create functionality to iOS app which will sent SMS or dial number if worker doesn't push button after some time period in app. App work completely without internet connection (in deep forest, badly covered area without internet connection or something like this). But I was searching possibilities whole day but nothing.

So, is there some solution how to do this or it is impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short **IMPOSSIBLE** in IOS; without voip (mean no internet).

IOS does not allow to override default Dial UI methods. or any changes.

So these functionalities cannot be implemented.

You can use your separate application, but VOIP for calling and some api for messaging.